# Relate field does not update during import in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have build custom Module in SugarCRM and added a custom field of type 'relate' and linked with Accounts module.
When I insert new record for this custom module via normal add/edit view it works perfectly alright and I can select an account via Account Name field. However when I use Import feature via CSV file it does not link with Accounts module however the Account already exists with same name. Same Account Name is working for other modules during import.
I am working on SugarCRM 6.5, I have build Custom Module via Module Builder than added custom field via Studio and also I have Many to Many relationship with this custom Contacts Module and Accounts Module.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated, I am new to sugarCRM so do not have much of experience and have spent lot of time already to figure this out.

Comment: Where is code of import where you have linked account?

Comment: I have used SugerCRM built-in feature of Import. No custom coding.